# Como criar uma migrate e adicionar uma coluna calculada em uma tabela ja existente no banco?

Tags: laravel, laravel-eloquent

Tenho a tabela avaliações que tem  as colunas nota1, nota2, nota3, nota4 criadas no banco e queria criar uma coluna media que ja calculasse a media automaticamente, como criar essa coluna calcular usando o migrate do laravel ?

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('avaliacoes', function(Blueprint $table)
        {
            $table->increments('id');           
            $table->integer('nota1')->default(0);
            $table->integer('nota2')->default(0);
            $table->integer('nota3')->default(0);
            $table->integer('nota4')->default(0);
            //criar columa media aqui = (nota1+nota2+nota3+nota4) / 4

        });
    }



nota1 | nota2 | nota3 | nota4 | // criar coluna media
 2    |    3  |     4 |     5 | // Media aqui
```

Comment: Na tabela você coloca os campos necessários para armazenamento, ou seja, se pode criar um campo media e pelo código (porque eu nem preciso desse campo) ou uma `trigger` pra calcular isso. Eu faria pelo código que é só criar mais uma configuração no seu model eloquent e o mesmo já faz isso pra você permitindo que tenha um campo calculado no seu modelo. O que acha?

Comment: Essa modelagem está meio estranha, mas dentro da estrutura que você tem aí você sí vai criar o campo, e dentro do seu *controller* (se você não usar injeção de dependência) você calcula a média das notas.

Comment: Consegui resolver, com a dica que vocês deram.